# How to write Xpath != (not equal) expression like (!='attr-2', !='attr-3, !='attr-4, etc)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can't find an example to solve quite simple situation. 
Need a propper pattern for multiple Xpath !=attribute (not equal) exclusion expression

Desired draft code is below:

```
  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <Document>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name() !='attr-1']" /> <!-- the question is How to continue typing or rewrite this "Not Equal" expression adding multiple condition like !='attr-2', !='attr-3, !='attr-4', etc ?? (copy all attributes except (attr-1, attr-2, attr-3...) -->
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

question - 2: Could it be another\others manner or style of this kind of expression to output the same result?

Comment: @*[name()[. !='attr-1' or . !='attr-2' or . !='attr-3']]

Comment: Which version of XSLT/XPath is that? In XSLT 2 and later I would suggest to use `@* except (@attr-1, @attr-2, @attr-3, @attr-4)` if the list of attributes you want to exclude is finite and known.

Comment: i may use both XSLT vers, so it could be very useful to know it in a both way)
Thank you!

Comment: @AmrendraKumar Which attribute would NOT be copied using your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy all attributes except attributes included in a list, it may be convenient to use the *identity transform* template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and add an exception:

```
<xsl:template match="@attr-1 | @attr-2 | @attr-3"/>
```

to suppress the attributes you want to omit.

---

Otherwise you need to get verbose:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name() ='attr-1' or name() ='attr-2' or name() ='attr-3')]"/>
```

Note the use of `not(a=b)` instead of `a!=b`.

---

In XSLT 2.0, you can use the `except` operator instead:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@* except (@attr-1, @attr-2, @attr-3, @attr-4)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is `not(name() = ('attr-1', 'attr-2', 'attr-3'))`. But when you're processing things conditionally by name, there are usually better ways of doing it in XSLT than a string comparison on the result of the `name()` function.